# Joining several dataframes with a large dataframe based on dictionary key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict, called y, consisting of dataframes in the following format.

```
y  =   {'000997': 0        2021   2020   2019
       000997  82700  83947  47939,
       '001011': 0        2021   2020   2019   2018   2017   2016   2015   2014   2013
       001011  18103  27799  60916  58039  59396  57372  54902  50534  49932,
       '001012': 0        2021   2020   2019   2018   2017   2016   2015   2014   2013
       001012  42853  59077  86729  85077  83622  81678  77562  73759  68902,
                 .................. 
                                  }
```

Each key of this dict is the name and the index of a one dimensional dataframe.
So calling y['000997'] will give:

```
            2021    2020    2019
000997     82700    83947   47939
```

and so forth

I also have a larger dataframe whose col_1 corresponds directly with the keys of the dict y, with the excpetion of the leading zeros being stripped.

```
df =         col_1      col_2    col_3           
         0    997        .         .           
         1    1011       .         .          
         2    1012       .         .          
        ...      ...      ...       ...
```

I want to join every one of the dataframes in y to its corresponding col_1 number such that the output looks like this:

```
df =         col_1      col_2    col_3    2021    2020    2019    2018    2017   ....  2013     
         0    997        .         .      82700   83947   47939   NaN     NaN    ....  NaN
         1    1011       .         .      18103   27799   60916   58039   59369  ....  49932  
         2    1012       .         .      42853   59077   86729   85077   83622  ....  68902  
        ...      ...      ...       ...
```

I have found on pandas.pydata.org:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#appending-rows-to-a-dataframe
that the 'Joining on index' function looks like it might work, so i tried to create a loop to join them

```
for i in df['col_1']:
    for j in y:
        if i==j:
            df.join(y[j])
        else:
            pass
```

This doesn't give an error, but it results in nothing.

I've also thought of stripping the indices of y of their leading zero, but have only found pieces of code that deal with strings containing zeros, but these dict keys are ints.

I would really appreciate any advice in the right direction about this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
for i in df['col_1']:
    for k in y.keys():
        _k = int(k.lstrip('0'))
        if i == _k:
            df.join(y[k])
        else:
            pass
```

The idea being that when you loop through the keys of the dictionary, which are currently strings, you remove the leading zeros and then convert them to integers before matching them to the column values in the dataframe.

I'm having a difficult time getting the formatting to work when I test based on the above example, but theoretically it should work?

Comment: This code yields an error: "KeyError: 997". I think this is referring to the very first entry, and i'm assuming it means they aren't equal?

Comment: I see, that error is because I modified the key variable but then tried to access it from the dictionary, which in that form doesn't exist.

And I think I may have misunderstood the dictionary formatting at first. Is this data coming from a text file or a dataframe? Is it possible to format it as:

`y = {
    '000997': {
        2021: 000997,
        2020: 82700,
        ...
}
}`